# Когда ставится запятая после "однажды"?

Tags: пунктуация

Однажды(,) двадцать лет спустя(,)...

Здесь ведь нужна запятая (или  запятые), если дальше идет продолжение предложения? А в названии фильма запятой нет.

Или например: "Однажды, в студеную зимнюю пору..." 
У Некрасова запятая есть, т.к. это однородные обстоятельства или уточнение, или дополнение (?).

А если: "Однажды(,) в далекой-далекой галактике(,)..." 
Запятые нужны или нет? Или здесь идут просто неоднородные обстоятельства, и запятые не нужны?

Или: "Давным-давно(,) в далекой-далекой галактике(,)..." 
Спрашиваю потому, что на большинстве сайтов "в далекой-далекой галактике" выделено запятыми.

В последних двух примерах идут вроде бы неоднородные обстоятельства (определения), и поэтому запятые как бы не нужны. Но можно ли принять слова "в далекой-далекой галактике"  за уточнение или за дополнение и выделить их запятыми?

Если нет, то получается: "В прошлом году в одном провинциальном городке произошел интересный случай: десятки людей увидели странные, светящиеся огни." 
В этом примере лишние запятые точно не нужны?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) В этой теме у автора текста большие авторские возможности, но и большая авторская ответственность, так как вы работаете как свободный художник. Вы как  бы создаете конструкцию из фраз, и она должна быть гармоничной и читаемой. Вы можете считать обстоятельства неоднородными, а можете обособить их, отнеся на второй план (в связи с распростраеноннстью, со значением уточнения и т.д.)

2) Вот примеры, в которых авторы совершенно свободно выбирают нужный им вариант:

Однажды вечером я сидел на своей любимой скамье и глядел то на реку, то на небо, то на виноградники.

Однажды в деревне он был свидетелем следующей сцены.

Однажды в пустыне, среди камней, я нашла осколок белого, чистого мрамора

Однажды, в ясный день ласковой и поздней осени, хозяева и гости отправились в этот монастырь.

Однажды в середине июня, под вечер, я, по обыкновению, ожидал Олесю.

3) Теперь о Галактике

Однажды в одной далекой Галактике... Однажды, в одной далеко-далекой галактике... В чем разница?  Просто фразу надо составить так, чтоб язык "не спотыкался" при чтении, чтоб мелодика фраз была плавной, естественной. Как только это у вас получится, можно приступать к объяснениям (искать уточняющие или неоднородные значения).